# How to change Ajax.ActionLink GET/POST url format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am issuing Get request from `Ajax.ActionLink` like this

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { Module  = (string)ViewBag.Module } ,new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get",
    UpdateTargetId = "DivCreate",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace})
```

> Here Master is Controller Name, Create is ActionMethod, Module is querystring

its generating following link

```
http://localhost:49598/Master/Create?Module=department
```

Since i have configured my RouteConfig like this

```
  routes.MapRoute(
             "Master",
             "Master/{Module}/{action}/{Id}",
              new { controller = "Master", action = "Index", Module = UrlParameter.Optional, Id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                  );
```

the result i want like this

```
http://localhost:49598/Master/department/create  // this link is working
```

My Create Method

```
  public ActionResult Create(string Module)
        {
            ViewBag.Module = Module;
            return PartialView("Pcreate");
        }
```

**PS: If possible**, I don't want to change my RouteConfig

any help?

Comment: Show you `Create()` method signature. Is it `Create(string module)`? And you need to delete `/{Id}",` from the route and `Module  = UrlParameter.Optional` (only the last parameter can be marked `Optional`)

Comment: Only the last parameter can be marked `Optional` but since you don't need `Id` and you need to supply `Module`, then it needs to be `url: "Master/{Module}/{action}", and `defaults: new { controller = "Master", action = "Index" }` and that route needs to be before the default route

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't need `ID` here but in some cases I am using `ID` for update/Edit/delete, that's why i marked as optional

Comment: So are you also wanting (say) `.../Master/department/edit/1`? In any case, only the **last** parameter can be marked `Optional`

Comment: yes you are right..I am doing like this and also `department` and `ID` are query strings

Comment: All you have to do is remove `Module = UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: @StephenMuecke its working, I have added new route Value as you suggested,Thank you :). If you willing to write this as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: I've marked it as a dupe, because the answers explain that you cannot have 2 optional parameters and also give some options for handling it.

Comment: okey, thank you :)